# date comparison "after" method returns false always

Tags: android, datetime, date-comparison

i am trying to compare two dates using "after" method in android. here is my two dates

```
currentDate :Fri Sep 12 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2014
expDate :Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015
```

my code is as follows

```
private boolean checkDate(String date) throws ParseException{

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    String cYear = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)).substring(0, 2);
    String digit1 = date.substring(2,4);
    String digit2 = date.substring(0, 2);
    String finalDate = cYear+digit1+"-"+digit2+"-"+"01";

    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    Date expDate = curFormater.parse(finalDate); 

    String cDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
    Date curentDate = curFormater.parse(cDate); 

    if(curentDate.after(expDate)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

but my if condition is always returns false. i don't know whats wrong with the code.
please some one help me about this..

thank you.

Comment: Convert dates to long and compare numbers. it will exclude most errors and simplify the solution in general

Comment: why You are taking a substring of the year? If You get Year from Calendar this will be 2014, but if You make this substring with parameters (0,2) it will return only 20

Comment: @Opiatefuchs that is because im enter short values in text fields.. like 0915.[MMYY]. so i need to check my current date and make the input date as a formal date.

Comment: ok, but If I look to Your code, it must return false everytime. Because You get the currentDate with new Date(), but Your expDate is for Year 2015. Or is it a variable Date and You set different ones?

Comment: expDate is changing according to the user... its not a fixed date.. i just wanted to check the entered expDate with the current date to check weather the credit card is still not expired